# Сохранение пропертей без перезаписывания в XML

Tags: java, xml, properties

Хочу сохранять значение переменной после каждого выполнения метода

Сейчас использую вот такое решение для сохранения значения
Но оно каждый раз его перезаписывает

```
public void saveParamChangesAsXML() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("email", userEmail);
    File f = new File("TestProperties.xml");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    props.storeToXML(out, "This is an optional header comment string");
}
```

А мне надо сохранять каждое значение(

Сейчас мой file.xml выглядит вот так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>This is an optional header comment string</comment>
<entry key="email">test123@mail.test</entry>
</properties>
```

Мне нужно чтоб списком там сохранялись все значения userEmail не зависимо от того когда были добавлены

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы хотели бы видеть все предыдущие значения `userEmail`? Если да, то в каком виде? Можете показать пример желаемого XML файла?

Comment: Да, я хочу чтоб значения пополнялись

Comment: Хм, `Properties` сам по себе не работает со списками. Можно сохранять значения в виде одной строки через запятую (вроде `test123@mail.ru,test@example.com`). Такой вариант устраивает?

Comment: Думаю, да, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) в основном работает со строковыми данными и не очень удобен для хранения списков.

Как вариант можно сохранять значения в виде одной строки через запятую (вроде `test123@mail.ru,test@example.com`).

Примерно так:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
File f = new File("TestProperties.xml");
//считываем предыдущее состояние файла
props.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream(f));
//считываем свойство
String emailsString = props.getProperty("emails", "");
//разбиваем по запятой
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emailsString.split(",")));
//добавляем новый email
emails.add(email);
//соединяем строки, записываем новое значение
props.setProperty("emails", String.join(",", emails));
//сохраняем файл
props.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream(f), "This is an optional header comment string");
```

В результате получится файл вроде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>This is an optional header comment string</comment>
<entry key="emails">,test@mail.com,test@example.com</entry>
</properties>
```

Текущий список email можно хранить в памяти и не перечитывать его каждый раз из файла.

Запятая используется в качестве разделителя. Это может привести к проблемам при работе с данными, в которых содержатся запятые. В этом случае понадобится дополнительная обработка.

Если предполагается расширять настройки приложения в дальнейшем, возможно, будет удобнее вместо `Properties` использовать [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) либо написать собственный класс настроек и сериализовать его в XML через [JAXB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding).

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ViktoriiaKorda Пожалуйста